# ModelChoiceField javascript onChange arguments

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a Django project that has a Students model with multiple fields, and I have implemented a ModelChoiceField form which drops down and allows for selecting a particular record in the Students table.

forms.py:

```
class StudentChoiceField(forms.Form):

    students = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Student.objects.values_list().order_by("last_name"),
        empty_label="(select student)",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'refresh()'})
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # without the next line label_from_instance does NOT work
        self.fields['students'].queryset = Student.objects.all().order_by("last_name")
        self.fields['students'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s %s" % (obj.last_name, obj.first_name)
```

The label_from_instance method is overridden, so that the drop-down form displays just two model fields (there are eleven total in the model).

When a student is selected, I want to update some textfields in the page to display the remaining fields of the model. Currently, have implemented a javascript function refresh() which is invoked for the onChange event of the StudentChoiceField form.

index.html (all_students_choice is the StudentChoiceField form):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<body>

<script>
    function refresh(){
        var id = document.getElementById("id_students").value;
        console.log(id);
    }
</script>

<div class="container">
    <form method=POST action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ all_students_choice }}
    </form>
</div>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

I have confirmed through the browser console that the javascript function is getting called, and printing the value of the ModelChoiceField form. As expected, after selecting an instance from the dropdown menu the value of the form element is the primary key of the table.

I need advice on the best approach to populate the textfields which I will be adding to display the remaining Student model fields (aside from first and last name). Should these be passed as parameters to the javascript function? Is there a best way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question with the approach that that was eventually used, in case it would be of assistance to someone else. Decided to render the same template, but with additional element in the context to reference the selected student. In the initial index home page, the selected_student is None:

```
def index(request):
    ....  

    context = {
        'students_choice_ln': students_choice_ln,
        'students_choice_fn': students_choice_fn,
        'selected_student': None
    }

    return render(request, 'awards/index.html', context)
```

For the select function, the selected_student is passed in through the context:

```
def select(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        ...
        student_id = ...
        selected_student = Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
        ...

        context = {
            ...
            'students_choice_ln': students_choice_ln,
            'students_choice_fn': students_choice_fn,
            'selected_student': selected_student,
            ...
        }

        return render(request, 'awards/index.html', context)
```

The template can then check whether the selected_student variable is available or not, and then accordingly display the additional fields in a separate div.

If there are any experienced web developers / django developers who see problems with this structure, perhaps they can point them out.